# Need a Search box in sheet 1 , which will search Sheet 2 like Cltr F in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to create a simple Search box like "**control F** "  in Sheet 1
which will display the Rows and column number if that "**word**" is present in Sheet 2 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: and the ouput when hitting `Find All` on the Find control is not sufficient?

Comment: control find at times doesn't  search properly , gets stuck on one cell and doesn't search the whole sheet , forcing you to do the same search multiple times if first search throws an error. - am hoping a dedicated search box would remove that headache